# Unir tablas SQL a partir de códigos distintos según los últimos dígitos del id

Tags: sql

Necesito obtener los datos de una tabla, a partir de otra, pero la clave en común no tiene el mismo código, son distintos, ejemplo:

Tengo en una tabla **FACULTAD**:

```
facu_codigo    facu_nombre
1              VICERRECTORIA
2              FACULTAD CS SOCIALES
3               .
4               .
.               .
.               .
10              .
```

y otra tabla **UNIDADES ACADÉMICAS**:

```
uaca_codigo

10

2001
2002
2003
.
.
2010
```

Entonces necesito obtener `nombre_facu` a partir de la unión entre `facu_codigo` y `uaca_codigo`, donde los últimos 2 dígitos de `uaca_codigo` da referencia al `facu_codigo` y de esa manera podría hacer la relación.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que **`uaca_codigo`** se convierta en los últimos dígitos para igualarlo a `facu_codigo` y que me dé el nombre?

Ejemplo:

```
2001 ---->  1
2005 ---->  5
2010 ----> 10
```

Comment: ¿En qué motor de base de datos (DBMS)? ¿De qué tipo son las columnas? Sería recomendable [edit] la pregunta para etiquetarla correctamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así de pronto se me ocurre que le restes 2000 al código de `uaca_codigo`, por ejemplo:

```
 SELECT * FROM FACULTAD F
 INNER JOIN UNIDADES_ACADEMICAS U ON F.FACU_CODIGO = (U.UACA_CODIGO -2000);
```

Comment: Si lo habia pensado y es buena idea, pero tambien hay un caso q se me olvido mencionar:

el facu_codigio 10 no hace relacion con uaca_codigo 2010 ( es el unico q no hace relacion), sino que hace relacion con uaca_codigo 10.
Ahi hay una excepcion q no sabria como hacerlo si le resto 2000

Comment: al final funciono con esto

 select facu_nombre from ACADEMIA.dbo.facultades  F INNER JOIN academia.dbo.unidades_academicas  U on f.facu_codigo = (u.uaca_codigo -2000)

ya que al ser bigint supongo que no hizo diferencias entre el valor 01 y 1 o 02 y 1, y coincidentemente me tomo el 10 q necesitaba.

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: De nada, si te funcionó puedes aceptar la respuesta como válida ;)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT [uaca_codigo], CONVERT(INT, RIGHT([uaca_codigo], 2))
FROM [dbo].[UNIDADES ACADEMICAS]
```

Así cortarías por la derecha 2 caracteres y convertido en numérico para quitar el 0 de su izquierda.

Un saludo